# Sort integers from text file in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

Right, so I've managed to get my program to concatenate my two text files, I now need to sort the created text file so they appear in numerical order. For example say Test1.txt contains the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 and Test2 contains the numbers 4,5,6,8, myoutput.txt should have 1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,8. I'm not massively familiar with sorting algorithms. I'm guessing I'll have to read the output file, sort them and the write to the output file again.

Here is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //collecting integers from first text file//
   ifstream file1("test1.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
   if(!file1)
   {
      cout << "Cannot open input test file 1.\n";
      return 1;
   }

   // collecting integers from second text file//
   ifstream file2("test2.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
   if(!file2)
   {
      cout << "Cannot open input test file 2.\n";
      return 1;
   }

   //outputting the concactonated file to myoutput.txt//

   ofstream cout("myoutput.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);

   if(!cout)
   {
      cout << "can't open output file ";
      return 1;
   }

   cout << file1.rdbuf();
   cout << " " << flush;
   cout << file2.rdbuf();

   ifstream sortfile("myoutput.txt, )

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the size of the text? Does it fit in memory?

Comment: @john: Note that because disk is NOT Random-Access-Memory, I am not sure that this trivial approach will be efficient, since your reading head on disk jumps from place to place enormous amount of times.

Comment: @john: This is wrong when talking about disks. If you do anything directly from disk, you need to jump the reading head twice/three times every iteration. One to the written array, and one/two (depending on your optimization level) to the source arrays. When talking about inefficient disk algorithm - it is crucial. Not efficient algorithm can take hours (though it is still `O(n)`) for reasonable input size.

Comment: Why do you open a TEXT file in BINARY mode?

Comment: @sellibitze Because in the code above, it is not being used as a text file. Text files are binary files too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read single numbers into integers, pushing them into an [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), then use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to sort them, then write them to an output file. Each one of these steps is trivial and has been covered in a multitude of SO questions.

Answer (score 2):

You should use merge sort for sort array from files like that.
Take a look at the merge sort algorithm at this http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/mergeSort.htm.
and the sample source code at this
http://www.c.happycodings.com/Beginners_Lab_Assignments/code27.html

Answer (score 1):

I think its better tp use merge sort in such situations. read one number from both the files compare them and insert the smallest into output file. by this approach i think time complexity will be less.